# Interpreting interactions of mixed model estimates correctly?

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, interpretation

I have data of the following form:

```
  Plot Period ChangeRate PlotType HurrStat
1    4      1   4.226524     Succ        N
3    4      2   4.465217     Succ        N
2    4      3   4.250807     Succ        N
4    5      1   4.647065     Succ        F
5    5      2   8.437362     Succ        F
6    5      3   1.826346     Succ        F
```

Where the `ChangeRate` of biomass (Mg/ha/year) during 3 different sampling `Periods`was determined. The data have 3 samples from each of 37 `Plots.` The plots also experienced differential Hurricane Fran damage between `Period` 2 and 3, which is captured by the categorical variable `HurrStat` (where `N` is no damage and `F` codes *for* damage). `PlotType` is also a 2-level factor not used.

I fit the following model using `lmer` (in R):

```
mod <- lmer(ChangeRate ~ factor(Period) * factor(HurrStat) + (1|Plot), data = dat, REML=F)
```

and followed that up by calculating bootstrapped confidence intervals for each predictor:

```
confint(mod,method='boot',nsim=10000)
```

I combined them into the following table showing `Estimates` and `2.5%` and `97.5%` confidence intervals:

```
                                   Estimates       2.5%      97.5%
(Intercept)                        3.4592000  2.2492249  4.6814362
factor(Period)2                    2.5679507  0.7930576  4.2767805
factor(Period)3                    2.9561185  1.2523120  4.6726818
factor(HurrStat)F                  0.3630296 -1.0398981  1.7304300  
factor(Period)2:factor(HurrStat)F -1.4151125 -3.3603946  0.5210217  
factor(Period)3:factor(HurrStat)F -4.4443273 -6.4183476 -2.4845560
```

**Are the below interpretations correct given these results?**

```
* Period 1: biomass change rate = 3.46 (95% CI 2.45, 4.68) Mg/ha/yr
* Period 2: 2.57 higher --> so 6.12 Mg/ha/yr 
* Period 3: 2.96 higher --> so 6.51 Mg/ha/yr
x Period 1 plots w/ Fran damage had 0.36 higher rates vs. Period 1 values above --> so 3.82 Mg/ha/yr
x Fran plots were -1.42 lower in Period 2 
* Plots with Hurr damage were -4.44 lower in period 3
    (So is this 3.46 + 2.96 + 0.36 -4.44, or do I ignore the non-significant 0.36?)

* = SIGNIFICANT EFFECTS   |   x = INSIGNIFICANT EFFECTS
```

Ultimately I want to know if plots experienced a slowing down of `ChangeRate` between periods (with a focus on `Period` 3).

- Is it safe to say form the results I got that: overall, `ChangeRate` *increased* in `Period` 3, but plots *impacted* by the hurricane actually decreased??

  - 6.51 rate in non-damaged plots vs 1.98 (*3.46 + 2.96 + -4.44*) rate in hurricane plots in Period 3  (vs. a mean Period 1 ChangeRate of 3.46)

Comment: How did you actually compute ChangeRate in each Period?

Comment: Biomass.year2 - Biomass.year1 / Year.year2 - Year.year1  (change in biomass devided by change in time for that given period)